# sml pattern don't see bound variable

Tags: pattern-matching, sml

I am doing coursera homework. Can anyone explain me why this code works:

```
  fun remove_card(cs: card list, c: card, except:exn)=
case cs of []=>raise except
 | x::xs =>( case (x=c) of true=> xs
                | _ => x::remove_card(xs,c,except))
```

but here it says "pattern redundant" as if c was undefined?

```
    fun remove_card(cs: card list, c: card, except:exn)=
case cs of []=>raise except
 | x::xs =>( case x of c=> xs
                | _ => x::remove_card(xs,c,except))
```

?

Another thing that helps is to change to "cs as x::xs" in function declaration, but why does it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cs as x::xs` binds cs and assumes it is nonempty, binding the head of cs to x and the tail to xs.  It's just a handy shorthand.

You have a typo in your example, but if you mean

```
case x of c => xs
```

then your'e binding c to x, which always succeeds.